# Logistic Regression with continuous exogenous variable

Tags: logistic, maximum-likelihood, statsmodels

So I'm trying to understand how a logistic regression can work with a continuous exogenous variable. 
I'm trying out this code with Python and `statsmodels`

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

X = pd.DataFrame({"v1": np.random.randn(10),
                  "v2": np.random.randn(10),
                  "v3": np.random.randn(10)})

y = np.abs(np.random.randn(10))
y /= y.max()

X = sm.add_constant(X)
print(X)
print(y)

>>>    const        v1        v2        v3
0    1.0  0.936366  1.733046 -1.431488
1    1.0  0.910953 -0.238240  1.391923
2    1.0 -0.547712 -0.027873  1.383092
3    1.0 -0.300446 -2.396009 -0.026780
4    1.0  2.797107 -0.727303  0.092896
5    1.0  1.059871 -0.191622  1.297797
6    1.0  0.449026  0.304059  0.499104
7    1.0  0.116308 -1.160632 -0.679466
8    1.0 -1.488820  0.559057 -0.657087
9    1.0  0.202345 -0.271734 -0.272912
>>> [1.         0.10742025 0.33584461 0.66050692 0.13558646 0.27380763
 0.18360422 0.13515612 0.56243905 0.20743443]
```

```py
my_results = sm.Logit(y, X).fit()
print(my_results.summary())

>>>
                           Logit Regression Results                           
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   No. Observations:                   10
Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                        6
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            3
Date:                Mon, 04 May 2020   Pseudo R-squ.:                  0.1391
Time:                        18:03:38   Log-Likelihood:                -5.0427
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                       -5.8575
Covariance Type:            nonrobust   LLR p-value:                    0.6527
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const         -0.3598      0.760     -0.473      0.636      -1.850       1.130
v1            -0.2760      0.686     -0.402      0.688      -1.621       1.069
v2             0.2650      0.687      0.386      0.699      -1.080       1.611
v3            -0.6850      0.827     -0.828      0.408      -2.306       0.936
==============================================================================
```

But what is actually going on under the hood? This seems to use the maximum likelihood to find the best coefficients, but I thought maximum likelihood is only defined for binary values

Comment: No, [maximum likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation) is a very general method.

Comment: @TimMak, right, it is
But I mean for a logistic regression I thought the data observed has to be 0s or 1s. You get a probability for each point from the logit, and then calculate MLE based on the fact each point was either observed as positive, or observed as negative. But what does it mean for a point to have a probability of 0.3, and have it being observed as 0.9. Would the contribution of that point to MLE then be 0.3 * 0.9 = 0.27?

Comment: I understand you now. The log-likelihood of logistic regression for a data point is given as $l(p) = y\log p + (1-y)\log(1-p)$. Usually $y$ is given as either 1 or 0, but as you can see, it doesn't hurt to have $y$ take any real number between 0 and 1 either.

Comment: @TimMak, thank you
So does that mean that the LL is not predicated on any distribution of the response? or is it just a coincidence it works out programmatically/algebraically but has no sensible basis?

Comment: Good question. I think strictly speaking maximum likelihood estimation (MLE) does require your response to have a specific distribution. However, in the case of the binary response it is not too uncommon to have the response given in probabilities as well. You could understand the problem now as instead of observing 0 or 1, we're observing 1 with probability p and 0 with probability 1-p. I'll see if I can come up with a better answer.

Comment: In the same time, maybe ask a separate question on CV with the title, say, "is there a statistical basis for using proportions or probabilities in the outcome in a logistic regression as opposed to binary values?"

Comment: Oh good idea!
Will do!
I think I'll run a logit with binarized versions drawn from the "observed probability" and see if I get the same results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two interpretations when for continuous response in Logit or GLM-Binomial

1. Maximum Likelihood for proportions using variance weights

A Binomial model can be represented as proportion with variance weights corresponding to the number of trials for any observation. This is just a reparameterization of the standard binomial model. 
This representation is internally used in statsmodels but can be used by the user with the `var_weights` option in statsmodels, and, IIRC, the weights option in R

2. Quasi-Likelihood Model

A special property of the (one-parameter) linear exponential family is that we can estimate the parameters of the mean function even if the distribution and variances or correlations are misspecified.
In GLM the mean function `m` is the inverse link function, so we have

E(y | X) = m(X beta)

This does not assume that the response variable has the same support restrictions as the original likelihood model. For example, we can use Logit to estimate a logistic curve or mean function, and we can use Poisson with log-link to estimate an exponential mean function for continuous data.

There is a literature that recommends using Poisson with continuous data as alternative to taking the log of the response variable.

In the QMLE case, the usual covariance of the parameter estimates is incorrect, and we need a Eicker/Huber/White sandwich form to have correct inference.

GLM models assume a variance function that is given by the family, e.g. Poisson assumes that the variance is equal to the mean. This is analogous to using some weights function in WLS. 
In the WLS case when we use an weights to represent heteroscedasticy, the consistency of the parameter estimates on the mean function does not depend on a correctly specified heteroscedasticity. Using heteroscedasticity weights improves asymptotic efficiency but does not change consistency of the parameters.

The same is true for GLM with the linear exponential family. So, QMLE with sandwich standard errors provides valid estimation and inference even if the variance assumption of the family does not hold for the data.

The main reference for Logit for fractional data is Papke and Wooldridge

Papke, L. E., and J. M. Wooldridge. 1996. Econometric methods for fractional response variables with an application to 401(k) plan participation rates. Journal of Applied Econometrics 11: 619–632.

Papke, L. E., and J. M. Wooldridge. 2008. Panel data methods for fractional response variables with an application to test pass rates. Journal of
Econometrics 145: 121–133.
Wooldridge, J.

see also https://www.stata.com/manuals14/rfracreg.pdf

One reference for using Poisson instead of Log-linear regression (i.e. log transformed response variable) is

Silva, J.S. and Tenreyro, S., 2006. The log of gravity. The Review of Economics and statistics, 88(4), pp.641-658.

Comment: "A Binomial model can be represented as proportion with variance weights corresponding to the number of trials for any observation. "
So if I'm understanding correctly, this means if I have a data point with a label of 0.9 and I feed it to a logit, that is the same as having the same data point 10 times, with 9 labels of 1, and a 10th label of 0?

Comment: Not in statsmodels `Logit` because it does not have weights. GLM Binomial with Logit link has the same underlying model as Logit, but allows specifying `var_weights`. The model needs the information about how many observations are included at each data point if it is not one. That's only possible in GLM.

Comment: oh I see what you're saying, if I have 0.9 as my observation the model needs to know if it's 90 vs 10, or 9 vs 1
But then can it be implicit all the weights are the same? i.e. use `Logit` with continuous values and assume all observations are y*100 out of 100?

Comment: For MLE, the standard errors depend on the actual number of observations or trials. If your don't specify the number of trials correctly, then you only have a QMLE as in my answer, and you need standard errors that are robust to likelihood misspecification. If you are not interested in inference, then that's irrelevant.

Comment: I'm not well versed with QMLE, can you link me up or explain to me how the exponential family is related to logit?

Comment: I added some references to the answer. Logit, Poisson and GLM with any standard family are members of the linear exponential family of distributions that all have the same nice properties.